How to leverage TypeScript to enforce an array is containing all property keys of an object type (and nothing else)?
I have a type describing an object
type MyObject = {
  foo: 1, 
  bar?: boolean
}

I want to create an array of all keys of given object, and I want TypeScript to notify me whenever my array is incomplete (is missing one or more keys of myObject), or includes items that are not keys of myObject.
One way I can think of is

creating an instance of an intermediary object with the same keys as myObject,
using TypeScript to ensure they have they have the same keys
generating a keys array from that object instance

// The object assignment should throw if I'm missing a key of MyObject
// and I should get `Object literal may only specify known properties` if I add extra props
const intermediaryObject: { [key in keyof Required<MyObject>]: true }  = {                 
  foo: true,
  bar: true
}

const myObjectKeys = Object.keys(intermediaryObject)

But this gets a bit annoying when working with large objects - is there a way to enforce those constraints without the need for creating intermediary objects?

TS doesn't have exhaustive arrays. The closest you can get is a generic helper function. See linked q/a for more information

Yes, I meant keys - my formulation was quite unfortunate. I updated my question to clarify - thank you for pointing it out :).

Well, exhaustive array type directly describing the array would be one possible (or actually impossible, as you pointed out) solution. It is hard for me to tell if another, less annoying solution (different than exhaustive array and the solution I produced) may exist.

Maybe? I don't know how to objectively describe what makes something "annoying". I'd think an object of type Required<MyObject> (or just Record<keyof MyObject, any>) would be the way to go, but you've already said that's annoying for big objects.
